# http to https with full path and queries [apache]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Sorry if this question already posted but I searched twice.

I want to redirect my `http://` domain to `https://` and also
 `http:// example.com/home` or `http:/ /www.example.com/home` to
 `https://example.com/home`

I google but didn't understand which one is perfect way to redirect.
I use this works but only when a person visit http, if someone direct open https than receiving error **This page has too many redirects**

.htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)

http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

I think this is for old to new domain but I don't want to redirect to another.
Same domain for redirection http to https.
Fix this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

or use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

port 80 is http and force to 443 https.

Comment: When i try to open www.site.com i got this error

`This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: You try first or second?

Comment: I tried both but now I figure it out myself successfully, i use this `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`